# detect when google earth plugin crash

Tags: javascript, google-earth-plugin

There is a way to detect from javascript if the google earth plugin is crashed, so I can reload automatically the page without user action?
Thanks

Comment: Take a look at the plugin specific classes: https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/ but I couldn't find anything useful. `google.earth` shows ErrorCode, but not sure when this is used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can directly assess whether the plug-in has crashed. However, you could set up an endless timer that is constantly checking something like `getView()`

```
function hasCrashed() {
     try {
          var view = ge.getView();
          if (view) {
          // plugin good
          } else {
          // plugin not good
          }
     } catch (e) {
         // plugin not good
     }
     // a timer that checks every second
     setTimeout('hasCrashed()', 1000);
}
```

I haven't tested that, but it should work. If not, try other options besides from `getView()` - perhaps `getWindow()` or `getGlobe()` options