# Refresh Google Earth plug-in without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

I made a web application that is heavily dependent on Google Earth plug-in. There are times that it crashes due to unknown reasons.

I was wondering if there ways to :

1. catch when the plug-in crashed
2. refresh the plug-in without refreshing the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your question number 1) - see [my answer on this SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12688626/detect-when-google-earth-plugin-crash)

For 2) - I haven't tested this, but when you detect the plug-in has crashed, try running your initial function again. The one that should look something like this

```
function init() {
  google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
}
```

Comment: I figured out that we need to clear the parent container first just so the existing instance will be removed. Perhaps before calling the google.earth.createInstace there should be $("#map3d").empty();